# Highlight Table Row using onMouseOver and onMouseOut with external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to highlight a table row (exluding the table head), but I can not use CSS hover. I must use JavaScript onMouseOver and onMouseOut events. The JavaScript must be contained in an external file.

I am already using the external JavaScript file to print the date in the footer.  For some reason onMouseOver and onMouseOut are not calling "trackTableHighlight" or "highlightTableRow". What am I doing wrong?

Here is test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Test</title>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </header>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </nav>

        <div class="main">
            <div class="middle-content">
                <br>
                <table class="stripe_table">
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>       
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody onMouseOver="trackTableHighlight(event, '#8888FF')" onMouseOut="highlightTableRow(0)">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <p>
                    Today is: 
                    <script>printDate();</script>
                </p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is test.js:

```
function printDate()
{
    document.write(Date());
}

function trackTableHighlight(mEvent, highlightColor)
{
  if (!mEvent)
    mEvent=window.event;

  // Internet Explorer
  if (mEvent.srcElement)
  {
    highlightTableRow( mEvent.srcElement, highlightColor);
  }
  // Netscape and Firefox
  else if (mEvent.target)
  {
    highlightTableRow( mEvent.target, highlightColor);      
  }
}

function highlightTableRow(myElement, highlightColor)
{
  var i=0;
  // Restore color of the previously highlighted row
  for (i; i<savedStateCount; i++)
  {
    restoreBackgroundStyle(savedStates[i]); 
  }
  savedStateCount=0;

  while (myElement && 
    ((myElement.tagName && myElement.tagName!="TR") || !myElement.tagName))
  {
    myElement=myElement.parentNode;
  }

  if (!myElement || (myElement && myElement.id && myElement.id=="header") )
    return;

  if (myElement)
  {
    var tableRow=myElement;

    if (tableRow)
    {
      savedStates[savedStateCount]=saveBackgroundStyle(tableRow);
      savedStateCount++;
    }

    var tableCell=findNode(myElement, "TD"); 

    var i=0;
    while (tableCell)
    {
      if (tableCell.tagName=="TD")
      {
        if (!tableCell.style)
        {
           tableCell.style={};
        }
        else
        {
          savedStates[savedStateCount]=saveBackgroundStyle(tableCell); 
          savedStateCount++;
        }
        tableCell.style["backgroundColor"]=highlightColor;

        tableCell.style.cursor='default';
        i++;
      }
      tableCell=tableCell.nextSibling;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is test.css:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF, #4F6D93) no-repeat;
    color: #666666;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

header {
    background-color: #000033;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

nav {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h1 {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

footer {
    font-size: 75%;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
    padding: 20px;
}

#wrapper {
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #90C7E3;
    min-width: 960px;
    max-width: 2048px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333333;
    position: relative;
}

.middle-content {
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}

.main {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 3px solid white;
    margin-left: 190px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}

table {
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 2px solid #90C7E3;
}

th, td {
    padding: 15px;
}

th {
    background: #000033;
    color: white;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: You can be really sneeky and just use the javascript file to append the css. https://jsfiddle.net/tmLvzur3/1/

Comment: 2 issues with this:

1. Just pasting the javascript from JSFiddle into my .js file does not seem to work. What is necessary to get the JSFiddle code working in an actual .js file?

2. This just uses javascript to perform css hover. I need to do this with onMouseOver and onMouseOut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little test in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a2Lxqxqe/2/ (I'm not sure about browser compatibility issues but you can see it working just fine in Chrome):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  var tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      tr[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
          this.style.backgroundColor = "#8888FF";
      });

      tr[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
          this.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
      });
  }
});


function printDate() {
  document.write(Date());
}
```

Instead of `addEventListener` you can use `attachEvent()` if you need support for: IE8 and below and/or Opera 6 and below. Here is a little reference to this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp

I wrapped the code in `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){ ... })` so the code executes after the DOM is loaded, if not you'll get an error when hovering.

Comment: Nice to hear it worked for you! ... hehehehe, don't worry about it. Knowing it helped you is enough :)